# Why should you not edit the .config kernel configuration file?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, configuration

```
# Automatically generated file; DO NOT EDIT
```

Is at the header of the kernel configuration file: /usr/src/linux/.config

My question is why shouldn't you edit this file? If I know exactly what I need, or what I want to remove, then what is the problem with editing this file directly?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's considered unsafe to edit `.config` because there are `CONFIG`-options which have dependencies on other options (needing some to be set, requiring others to be turned off, etc.).  Other options aren't meant to be set by the user at all, but are set automatically by `make config` (resp. `Kconfig` to be correct) depending on architecture details, e.g. availability of some hardware dependant on architecture variant, like an MMU.

Changing `.config` without using `Kconfig` has a high chance of missing some dependency, which will either result in a non-functioning kernel, build failures, or unexpected behaviour (i.e. the change being ignored, which usually is very confusing).

Answer (score -3):

Because it is automatically generated: it is generated from other files, that can be edited.

Comment: This isn't the case: you can edit it by hand and then use one of the edit interfaces and it will not overwrite these changes provided they don't conflict (which is the biiger issue, as described in [Andreas Wiese's answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/164230/6761).

Comment: That's a rather unsatisfying answer.  What if I don't change those files?  That's like saying »Don't write your sendmail config yourself, you don't want to do this!  You should use `m4`!«  Anyways it would be perfectly fine to write it on your own (there are some really weird guys out there ;) ).  The usual case being autogenerating files is not a valid reason for HAVING to use those tools.